# Excluding specific classes within a dependent jar - GRADLE

Tags: java, gradle

I have a jar file : sp-common-types.jar which is provided by a different team. This has around 6 classes. I do not want to include 2 classes out of these. I am able to exclude the jar using the statement below in gradle. If I want to exclude specific classes from the jar , how can it be achieved.

> compile("com.xyz.sp:sp-boot:0.1.1"){
>           exclude group: "com.xyz.sp",  module: 'sp-common-types'
>       }

Comment: Do you want them excluded when it comes in as a dependency, or when you are compiling the final jar? If it is the first, then I am not sure that is built in with gradle.

Comment: I want to exclude it when it comes as a depedency. Alternatively , if I can selectively include only specific class files from a jar, that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to exclude files/classes at dependency import time. The only solution I can think of that **might work**, but would be a gross solution, would be to write a task that manually goes and deletes the folder structures that you don't want from the jar you imported.